# After Update, App Doesn't Load Existing Files from Documents Folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

I'm having an issue with loading existing images from the App's Documents Folder after ad-hoc update.

I've searched the internet for answers and I've found that I must use relative paths to files in order for the path to remain the same when the App is updated.

Can someone please show me how to do it ?

Right now I use the following to save the files (images) when ImagePicker finishes:

```
NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-profilePhoto.jpg",[NSDate date]];
NSArray *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", paths, imageFilename];
```

Please help me out !

Comment: please NSLog the imagePath and what is displayed on console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

Instead of loading the images from the full path, I chose to make the system search for them after their name.

So instead of:

```
//Full path stored in a dictionary:
    profilePhotoPath = [userDict objectForKey:@"profilepic"];
//Load the image from path:
    profilePhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:profilePhotoPath];
```

I now use the following:

```
//Load image from documentsDirectory, filename
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    profilePhotoPath = [userDict objectForKey:@"profilepic"];
    profilePhotoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[profilePhotoPath lastPathComponent]];
    profilePhoto = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:profilePhotoPath];
```

By using "lastPathComponent" attribute I'm basically stripping out everything from the path except the filename and then I use NSSearch to give me my file.

Answer (score 0):

This line makes the problem

```
NSArray *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

Here the issue is the variable paths is of type `NSArray` not `NSString`

Change it to,

```
NSString *paths = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

or

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *paths = [path objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I doesn't work because I've tried earlier the following:  imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], imageFilename];

Comment: Ok, I'll check now. Thank you for trying to help me out !

Comment: with pleasure, hope this will help you to solve the problem :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... just tested it again, after update it doesn't load the image files because the path to directory gets changed. That's why I need relative paths to images

Comment: IMAGE PATH: /var/mobile/Applications/70BEA46A-1C8B-4415-B6B3-6D6204316CF1/Documents/2012-10-20 10:10:54 +0000-profilePhoto.jpg

Comment: Why are you using `[NSDate date]` it will return the current time. If there is no image with that name, then how it can be loaded ? Also is the NSLog same before and after updating the app ? I think it is same except the file name.

Comment: I load the images from the path which is stored in a plist file. The code above works just fine. I can see the images when using the app, but if I update the app, the App folders receive a new hex prefix